# Update List base on another list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How Can I update an Array based on another Array?

This is how I tried to do:

```js
   
var ref = [
    {
      "name": "Jack",
      "title": "Manager",
      "description": "",
    },
    {
      "name": "Steve",
      "title": "CEO",
      "description": "A test description",
    }
  ];

var elem = [
    {
      "name": "Jack",
      "title": "Manager",
      "description": "",
    },
    {
      "name": "Steve",
      "title": "CEO",
      "description": "A test description",
    }
  ];


for (var i = 0; i < ref.length; i++) {

 ref.indexOf(elem[i]) === -1 ? ref.push(elem[i]) : console.log("This item already exists");

}
console.log(ref);
console.log(elem);
```

This Loop caused an error because the length is changing after each iterate.

What I want is, to add each element from `elem object` if it doesn't exist in `arr object` and of course stays in **JOSN** format. In my example, it doesn't have to change.

Comment: so your 2 input arrays are identical, what do you want to modify?

Comment: you don't compare objects correctly. While contents of objects may be same, still you might have different references. And comparison as well as indexOf uses reference comparison.

Comment: What happens if you have two "Jack", with same "title", but a slight difference in the description? In other words, what is the primary key of each entry?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to run the loop over `elem`. Also you can't compare objects like that because references will differ, so you will have to do deep check, something like this should work:

```js
   
var ref = [
    {
      "name": "Jack",
      "title": "Manager",
      "description": "",
    },
    {
      "name": "Steve",
      "title": "CEO",
      "description": "A test description",
    }
  ];

var elem = [
    {
      "name": "Jack",
      "title": "Manager",
      "description": "",
    },
    {
      "name": "Steve",
      "title": "CEO",
      "description": "A test description",
    }
  ];


for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    var found = false;
    for (var j=0; j<ref.length; j++){
        var count = Object.keys(elem[i]).length;
        for(var key in elem[i]){
            if(ref[j][key] === elem[i][key])
                count--;
        }
        if (count === 0){
           found= true;
           break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
       ref.push(elem[i]);
 }

console.log(ref);
console.log(elem);
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked, But any better solution for that? I mean because of 3 times Loop!

Comment: I think 2 loops are required to compare each element inside two arrays, without indexOf. The third array is required because of deep checking. But third loop will only run as many times as there are keys in an object, which I suppose will be a small number compared to number of elements in arrays. But the third loop can be avoided if there was an identifying key in your objects, but you haven't mentioned that so I assume you need to compare all keys in objects.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid nested loops, you could build a `Set` with each of the keys that you have in `ref`. Let's say you consider the name to be the identifying key, then it would look like this:

```
ref = ref.concat(elem.filter(function (o) {
    return !this.has(o.name)
}, new Set(ref.map(o => o.name))));
```

So, this builds the `Set` by taking all the names in `ref`, passes that as `this` to a `filter` callback, which checks for each `elem` entry whether it has a `name` that is in the set. If so, it is excluded by the `filter`. This filtered result is concatenated to `ref`.

If your identifying key is something else, like the combination `name` and `title`, then adjust the function that is used in the last `map(.......)`, and apply the same logic in `has()`.

Here is a fiddle (with slightly different sample data) that uses the combination of `name` and `title` as identifying key:

```js
var ref = [{
  "name": "Jack",
  "title": "Manager",
  "description": "",
}, {
  "name": "Steve",
  "title": "CEO",
  "description": "A test description",
}];

var elem = [{
  "name": "Jack",
  "title": "Manager",
  "description": "",
}, {
  "name": "Steve",
  "title": "Programmer",
  "description": "Java addict",
}];

ref = ref.concat(elem.filter(function (o) {
    return !this.has(JSON.stringify([o.name, o.title]))
}, new Set(ref.map(o => JSON.stringify([o.name, o.title])))));

console.log(ref);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```